React-Laravel-Inertia V2.0 Pagination with Collections
I have a problem with a Laravel/React/Inertia V2.0 application. I want to implement some infinite scrolling pagination. There is the new Inertia::merge() accessor, that helps merging paginated content. I am using the corresponding <WhenVisible/> component.
The problem occurs, if I try to paginate collections of a resource. The first page works fine, the second request (started when the <WhenVisible/> component at the end of the page is reached) and is called with feature?page=2. So far so good - the second part of data is added to the first one. If I reach the end of the page again, the backend is called with feature?page=2 instead of feature?page=3. The wrongly "third" (as it is the second dataset again) data is then added to the features array. Am I missing something?
Somehow it seams, as the "page" prop returned from laravel is not properly updated in react.
Here is my code:
Backend FeatureController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Resources\FeatureListResource;
use Inertia\Inertia;
class FeatureController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $paginated = Feature::latest()->paginate();

        return Inertia::render('Feature/Index', [
            'features' => Inertia::merge(fn() => FeatureListResource::collection($paginated)->collection->toArray()),
            'page' => Inertia::merge(fn() => $paginated->currentPage())
        ]);
    }
}

Frontend Index.tsx
export default function Index({ auth, features, page }: PageProps<{ features: PaginatedData<Feature>, page: number }>) {
    return (
        
    <AuthenticatedLayout
      header={
        <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold leading-tight text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200">
          Features
        </h2>
      }
    >
      <Head title="Features" />

      {features.map(feature => (
        <FeatureItem key={feature.id} feature={feature} />
      ))}

      <WhenVisible
        always
        fallback={<div className='text-gray-200'>Loading {page + 1}</div>}
        params={{
          data: { page: page + 1 },
          only: ['features', 'page'],
          preserveUrl: true
        }}
      >
        <p className='text-gray-200'>
          Load page {page + 1}
        </p>
      </WhenVisible>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
    )
}

What I also tried
I tried returning the feature collection as it was
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Resources\FeatureListResource;
use Inertia\Inertia;
class FeatureController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $paginated = Feature::latest()->paginate();

        return Inertia::render('Feature/Index', [
            'features' => Inertia::merge(FeatureListResource::collection($paginated))
        ]);
    }
}

and access the current page from the frontend with features.meta.current_page, but then the data is not merged correctly and only the second dataset stays in the "features" prop. Also the feature?page=2 does not change to "page=3"
Thanks in advance!!

If infinite scrolling is becoming complex to handle, consider using Laravel's cursor pagination instead of traditional offset pagination. Cursor pagination eliminates page number issues and improves performance on large datasets.
$paginated = Feature::latest()->cursorPaginate(10); 

return Inertia::render('Feature/Index', [
'features' => FeatureListResource::collection($paginated),
'pagination' => [
    'next_cursor' => $paginated->nextCursor(),
    'has_more_pages' => $paginated->hasMorePages(),
],
]);

Adjust the frontend to work with next_cursor instead of page.
